# Update Help Center page about login credentials

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, login

The instructions and images on page titled [How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) are inaccurate after the introduction of [new profile pages](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/).

Link "My Logins" is one of the options on "Edit Profile & Settings" page.

Comment: Related MSE post: [Remove the unnecessary text about "on most sites" from the login credentials Help Center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289073/335251)

Comment: There's a lot of outdated info on the `/help/edit-credentials` Help Center page... From what I can tell from the "[Your logins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current)" page (and based on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/335251)), the whole section mentioning OpenID in the first paragraph is no longer accurate; the only options now are adding an SE username/password combo, Google login, or Facebook login. The "Edit Profile and Settings" tab has been renamed to "Settings", and "My Logins" in the settings sidebar has become "Your logins".

Comment: (And of course, the screenshot needs to be updated as well – or simply removed, since it'd become out of date if the UI ever changes again in the future.) Anything else I missed?

Comment: GitHub login is also one of the choices.

Comment: True – though that's only an option on SO (which will need to be noted on the page as well).

Comment: Ah, after *8* years the problem is fixed, woah, yeah, party.